# Convert relative imports into absolute imports in Typescript

Tags: regex, typescript, visual-studio-code, import

Setting the `baseUrl` property to `src` in the `.tsconfig` has allowed me to import modules relative to the `baseUrl` like this:

`import { ArrowRightIcon } from 'Shared/icons/navigation'`

instead of :

`import { ArrowRightIcon } from '../../../Shared/icons/navigation'`

### Question

How can I efficiently transform the thousands of such relative imports into absolute imports in my application since `Find All` functionality of any IDE does not understand the context?

Currently, I have to replace all the occurrences of `../../../Shared/`, `../../../../Shared/`, so on... with `Shared/` and for all the directories in `src`. Even if I do that with help of `regex`, it won't help in the cases like example no. 2 below.

### Other examples:

1. `import { getActiveTabIdx } from 'Shared/utils/shared.helpers'`

instead of `import { getActiveTabIdx } from '../../../../../../../Shared/utils/shared.helpers'`

2. `import { TabWithLink } from 'Shared/components/Header'`

instead of `import { TabWithLink } from '../../components/Header'`

3. `import { layoutReducer } from 'Layout/state/layout.reducer'`

instead of `import { layoutReducer } from '../../Layout/state/layout.reducer'`

My directory structure is:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── Shared
│   │  ├── components
│   │  ...
│   ├── Notification
│   │  ├── components
│   │  ...
│   ├── Planning
│   │  ├── components
│   │  ...
│   ├── Behaviour
│   │  ├── components
│   │  ...
│   └── Layout
│   │  ├── components
│   │  ├── state
│   ...
...
```

> Currently installed version:
>
> - typescript: 4.2.4
> - vscode: 1.57.1